# Programs and windows open randomly after waking up PC from sleep on windows 10. Most often it's Bankrobber.exe or the native Calculator app. any fix?

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep

The problem is sometimes when I wake my Windows PC up from sleep it ends up opening a random app like Bankrobber.exe (an sp404 memory card formatting software), the native windows calculator app, or the pictures folder. Most often it is Bankrobber.exe that opens. the second most common app that opens is the Native calculator app. Never is it both together. And it happens every 3-5 sleep cycles. it never happens on startup (ie restarting or shutting down and turning it back on) it only happens after waking up from sleep and its never more than one app. I have tried looking at ProcessExplorer but that didn't show me anything even though I had the Autostart column activated. I don't think the problem is related to a specific app since it affects the Native Calculator app as well as the Pictures folder. Google's indexing has a problem where when I try to search for the solution it searches for problems relating to PC's randomly waking up from sleep. That is not my problem at all. the sleep function works perfectly except for this issue. It isn't bluescreen level but it is kinda annoying. has anyone had a similar issue in the past and was able to fix it? I am willing to provide more information if needed

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: already did multiple times and didnt solve the issue

Comment: Did SFC find anything on the first scan?

Comment: Do you have a keyboard shortcut manager installed, such as AuthoHotkey or Clavier+? If so, try shutting the app just before sleep to see if that is causing the issue.

Comment: @harrymc SFC found nothing

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I dont have any keyboard shortcut manager installed. just now again I woke up the pc from sleep and Bankrobber.exe opened up

Comment: Try Autoruns, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns , to nsee what starts automatically.